# How to hide parent folder name from url in a wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

We have installed our wordpress into a sub directory in root folder. like this

```
http://www.domainname.com/wp/wp-login.php
```

How can we hide `wp` form the url so that it looks like wordpress is installed on root folder.
We tried to put only the `index.php` file from `wp` directory to root folder and change the include paths and it didnt worked. I have no experience in `htaccess`. So if anyone can help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)           /index.php [QSA]
```

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work. But Wordpress manages it's own .htaccess and I think it will cause some problems when you want to use SEO friendly URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has answered this question that you have here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory